# Printing Sigma Symbol in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode, character-encoding

How do I display "Σ" using a `System.out.println();` statement...??

P.S.: Using Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3a3/index.htm, the unicode value for this symbol is U+03A3, so you just have to use the unicade escape sequence :

```
System.out.println("\u03A3");
```

The problem, now, is that the console where the String is printed must support unicode and use a font where this symbol is supported, else you'll probably see a '?' character instead of the sigma.

Comment: Yes...!!!! when i tried running this in eclipse, i got '?'. I thought I was wrong.. Thank u :) problem solved...